# Status () function

Tags: c++

I am editing a program written in C++ and Python. I don't understand this line `if ((*p)->status() != 1) continue;` in below mentioned code.

```
for (HepMC::GenEvent::particle_const_iterator p = HepMCEvt->particles_begin();
     p != HepMCEvt->particles_end(); ++p) {
  int pid = (*p)->pdg_id();
  double pt = (*p)->momentum().perp();  // transverse momentum directly
  double px = (*p)->momentum().px();
  double py = (*p)->momentum().py();
  double pz = (*p)->momentum().pz();
  double e = (*p)->momentum().e();      // time component of momentum
  double eta = (*p)->momentum().eta();  // Pseudo-Rapidity
  double phi = (*p)->momentum().phi();  // Azimuthal Angle
  double pxlep = 0;
  double pylep = 0;
  double elep = 0;
  double pxnu = 0;
  double pynu = 0;
  double enu = 0;

  if ((*p)->status() != 1) continue;

  if ((pid) == 11 || (pid) == 13 || (pid) == -11 || (pid) == -13) {
    if (!FoundLepton) {
      pxlepton = px;
      pylepton = py;
      pzlepton = pz;
      elepton = e;
      FoundLepton = true;
    }
  }
```

What is its function?

Comment: It calls a member function `status()` of the particle, and tests if the return value equals `1` or not

Answer (score 1):

`p` seems to be an iterator. You dereference it (as `*p`) to get the object or value the iterator is "pointing" to.

In this case it seems that `*p` is a pointer to an object, so we dereference it using the "arrow" operator `->` to get the `status` member function which is called.

And the result of the `status` function call is then compared to the integer value `1`.

If the result of the comparison is true (i.e. `status()` returns value not equal to `1`) then the statement `continue;` is executed, which reiterates the closest surrounding loop.

---

One way to "decipher" statements and expressions you don't understand, is to split it up into smaller parts, and try to understand each small part by itself.

With the example statement you have:

```
if ((*p)->status()!=1)continue;
```

we can split it up as follows:

```
auto dereferenced_p = *p;
auto result_of_status = dereferenced_p->status();
auto result_of_comparison = result_of_status != 1;

if (result_of_comparison)
    continue;
```